# Converting .bin to .mat file

Tags: matlab, bin

### Current situation

Currently we have a machine that generates a .bin file of the logging.
Now we use a C# application to read the .bin file and save everything in a .csv file. After that we load in the .csv file in Matlab.

### My question

Is there a better/more efficient way of converting the .bin file so we can use it in Matlab?

### What I tried

I looked into converting .bin files to .mat files and found out that you can change .mat files to .bin files with this command `movefile('FileName.mat', 'FileName.bin')` inside Matlab, so I changes the extensions of the files in that command, but that didn't work. (Not that I assumed it would work :P)
I also looked into this command `tempRow = fread(fileread, ncols, 'uint=>uint');` but here it only works when you have only integers. And the .bin file I am working with contains bools, int16, reals and udint.

Comment: You will need to know how the bin file is created and what type of codification it uses. If you have access to the C# source code you can reverse-engineer it to know how the bin file is converted to csv.

Comment: I do not really understand your question. You cannot change that it is created as  a .bin file, yes? So how is it different whether you turn it into a .mat file or a .csv file? I mean you just use `csvread` instead of `load`? Which benefit are you looking for?

Comment: Some example of the data your are trying to import would help.

Comment: It depends on how the binary file is written. If it only contains one or more scalar(s)/vector(s)/matrix(-ices), a combination of `fopen()`,`fread()` and `fclose()` will allow you to read the quantities into your MatLab workspace. Once you have read in all that you want to save, a simple `save()` will do the trick.